# Unilaterally Bickering Soliloquies

Tags: riddle

I flash... But, illumination is not always to be found
I recall... Yet, others give me amnesia
I am little... Still, I can be quite large
I will carry things for you... Conversely, I must receive them first
I communicate very fast... Still, you prefer it that way
I am bigger than my older brothers... Yet, I am much smaller than they
I used to only have one friend... But, I now play with many

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it a

> USB Drive

I flash... But, illumination is not always to be found

> Also called Flash drives

I recall... Yet, others give me amnesia

> Memory storage, and deletion

I am little... Still, I can be quite large

> Finger sized, but with many gigs of space

I will carry things for you... Conversely, I must receive them first

> Portable information store

I communicate very fast... Still, you prefer it that way

> USB protocols are getting faster

I am bigger than my older brothers... Yet, I am much smaller than they

> More memory, less physical size than earlier portable storage CD/Floppy

I used to only have one friend... But, I now play with many

> Started out only really working with PCs, now work with many devices.

Comment: Well, that was quick haha. You're correct. Although line 1 isn't the clue I had in mind. Also, I have a little hidden clue :P

Comment: @dcfyj Maybe you were referring to damaged ones.

Comment: The clue `flash` might be understood here as `blinking [led]` indicating activity. It is not mandatory though, to have one.

Comment: The led is the reason I put the second half of that line, to help people realize that "Flash" wasn't talking about lights.

Comment: I assume it has more to do with the fact that... hfo qevirf ner pnyyrq synfu qevirf orpnhfr gurl hfr synfu zrzbel (pnyyrq guvf orpnhfr bs ubj snfg gurl pbhyq jevgr) (Rot13) (Source: Quora but don't want to post the link since it has a clue about the riddle in it)

uggcf://jjj.dhben.pbz/Jul-vf-synfu-zrzbel-pnyyrq-fb

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> A computer (or USB system)

I recall... Yet, others give me amnesia

> Save and deleting stuff

I am little... Still, I can be quite large

> Computer (or USB) of all size

I will carry things for you... Conversely, I must receive them first

> Got your file

I communicate very fast... Still, you prefer it that way

> NEEEED RAM (or USB3)

I am bigger than my older brothers... Yet, I am much smaller than they

> Much bigger RAM (bytes), but smaller

I used to only have one friend... But, I now play with many

> Only one user. But now connected

Comment: All the "I"s refer to the same object, you're jumping to different things.

Comment: You also skipped the first line entirely.